# How to secure a server-side session in flask?

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug, flask-session

The issue I am facing is that `Werkzeug 1.0.0` has removed deprecated code, including all of  `Werkzeug.contrib` so when I use flask-sessions I get

```
from werkzeug.contrib.cache import FileSystemCache
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'werkzeug.contrib'
```

So the solution suggested is to downgrade the `werkzeug to 0.16.0` which I did. But now the issue is

```
cannot import name 'ContextVar' from 'werkzeug.local'
```

For which the solution provided is to upgrade werkzeug to 2.0 or above.

What should I do to fix the flask-Sessions? How can I store session securely?

I saw some alternatives to import `from cachelib import FileSystemCache` instead of  `from werkzeug.contrib.cache import FileSystemCache` in `sessions.py` but the issue is it doesn't encrypt the session files.

How can I solve this? Also there is an issue with flask sessions that the sessions are not cleared when browser is closed I have specifically given `app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False` at the begining.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a part of your question is answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68060390/6361745

To make the flask-sessions encrypted on the server-side too, you may use your own session management by creating a db and storing only encrypted values.

For the last part of your question on deleting the cookie data. I don't think there is any way we can alter the browser cookies. We only have control on the server session data. However, we can set up an expiry time for them. Try this:

```
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = True
app.config['PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME'] = 60 #in seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the Werkzeug version to solve this issue.

```
pip uninstall Werkzeug
pip install Werkzeug
```